# Find result in one json object based on outcome from other object?

Tags: jquery, json

I have 2 json objects and i want to find the value in one based on the key in the other (hope that makes sence for you).

```
var items = {'item1': 20,'item2':10};
var other = {'item1': 70,'item2':40};
var output = "";

$.each(items, function (key, value) {
   output = output + other.key;  
});

$(".test").append(output);
```

First do a for-each on 1 object and then i want to use the outcome key to get the item from the 2. object.

So the code should give this

```
output = output + other.item1
output = output + other.item2
```

[1]https://jsfiddle.net/6uujc1af/

Its the other.key part that doesnt work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this using square bracket notation `[]`

```
var items = {'item1': 20,'item2':10};
var other = {'item1': 70,'item2':40};
var output = "";

$.each(items, function (key, value) {
   output = output + other[key];  
});

$(".test").append(output);
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6uujc1af/1/

Comment: @DennisSødalChristensen np! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `[]` object notation when you have variables as keys

```
 $.each(items, function (key, value) {
   output = output + other[key];  
 });
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/1Lcfy643/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Should re-define your json object, and change the way to access the key:

```
var items = {item1: 20, item2: 10};
var other = {item1: 70, item2: 40};
var output = "";

$.each(items, function (key, value) {
    output += other[key];  
});

$(".test").append(output);
```